# Adding large number of views in UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I am working on an app which have to calculate solution and show calculation steps. Problem is solved by iterative method, which sometimes require large number of steps. All calculation steps are to be shown as Custom Views defined by me. I am adding these views in root view as and when it is prepared.

When number of steps are large, adding view in UI requires much memory and app becomes unresponsive also. For this task, I cannot use `AsyncTask`, because it cannot add or update view while `doInBackground`. And it is not possible to add view in `onPostExecute`. I have to add it intermittently while calculating solution.

Any help for this problem?
(Pls, forgive me if question is not well understandable. I am new to Stack Overflow.)

Comment: try to use `Fragment` instead of `Custom View` and replace them by `Fragment Manager`